# How to check for database changes of in-memory records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to check if an `ActiveRecord` instance was changed database-wise. Something like:

```
p1 = Product.first
p1.name #=> "some name"

p2 = Product.first
p2.name = "other name"
p2.save #=> true

p1.database_changed? #=> true
```

I'm currently comparing the record's attributes to the persisted attributes:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  def database_changed?
    Product.find(id).attributes != attributes
  end

end
```

This seems to work, but I'm wondering if there is a built-in way to find database changes?

Comment: do you know about `dirty attributes`?

Comment: @Зелёный dirty attributes are basically the opposite - they track in-memory changes, I'm looking for database changes. In the example above, `p1` doesn't change and `p1.changed?` would return `false`.

Comment: @Зелёный your comment pointed me in the right direction, thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [Зелёный's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012800/how-to-check-for-database-changes-of-in-memory-records#comment38894739_25012800) I've reviewed `ActiveModel::Dirty` and realized that it almost does what I want. There's already an in-memory state (the record's attributes) and a database state (handled by `ActiveModel::Dirty`). I just need a method to update the database state, leaving the in-memory state unchanged:

```
def refresh
  @changed_attributes = {}
  fresh_object = self.class.unscoped { self.class.find(id) }
  fresh_object.attributes.each do |attr, orig_value|
    @changed_attributes[attr] = orig_value if _field_changed?(attr, orig_value, @attributes[attr])
  end
  self
end
```

- `@changed_attributes` is `ActiveModel::Dirty`'s hash to store changed values. We obviously have to reset it.
- `fresh_object` is the same record, freshly fetched from the database ([this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L394) comes from `reload`, thanks [emaillenin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25013884/477037)).
- Within the loop, each (fresh) attribute is compared to the corresponding (in-memory) attribute. If they differ, it is added to the `@changed_attributes` hash. [This line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb#L58) comes from `ActiveRecord`'s `dup` method. (it's actually from a private method called by `dup`, and `_field_changed` is private, too. It might be better to use `ActiveRecord`'s public API, but I was lazy)
- Finally, `refresh` returns `self` for convenience, just like `reload` does.

Here's an example usage:

```
p1 = Product.first
p1.name           #=> "some name"
p1.changed?       #=> false

p2 = Product.first
p2.name = "other name"
p2.save           #=> true

p1.refresh
p1.name           #=> "some name"
p1.changed?       #=> true
p1.name_changed?  #=> true
p1.name_was       #=> "other name"

p1.name = "other name"
p1.name_changed?  #=> false

p1.changed?       #=> true
p1.changes        #=> {"updated_at"=> [Tue, 29 Jul 2014 21:58:57 CEST +02:00, Tue, 29 Jul 2014 15:49:54 CEST +02:00]}
```

Comment: cool @Stefan, i thinking about `dirty` first because it is opposite.

Answer (score 1):

The Rails way to to do this is to use [reload](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Persistence/reload) method on the ActiveRecord object.

```
  def database_changed?
    attributes != reload.attributes
  end
```

## Terminal 1

```
2.1.2 :001 > c = Car.find(1)
  Car Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars"  WHERE "cars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Car id: 1, name: "Audi", model: "R8", created_at: "2014-07-29 11:14:43", updated_at: "2014-07-29 11:14:43">
2.1.2 :002 > c.database_changed?
  Car Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars"  WHERE "cars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => false
2.1.2 :003 > c.database_changed?
  Car Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars"  WHERE "cars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => false
2.1.2 :004 > c.database_changed?
  Car Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars"  WHERE "cars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => true
```

## Terminal 2

```
2.1.2 :001 > c = Car.find(1)
  Car Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars"  WHERE "cars"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Car id: 1, name: "Audi", model: "R8", created_at: "2014-07-29 11:14:43", updated_at: "2014-07-29 11:14:43">
2.1.2 :002 > c.model = 'A5'
 => "A5"
2.1.2 :003 > c.save!
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "cars" SET "model" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "cars"."id" = 1  [["model", "A5"], ["updated_at", "2014-07-29 11:15:32.845875"]]
   (1.2ms)  commit transaction
 => true
2.1.2 :004 >
```

Comment: `reload` changes the receiver, I'd prefer a non-destructive method.

Answer (score 1):

```
def database_changed?
  self.class.where(self.class.arel_table[:updated_at].gt(updated_at)).exists? self
end
```

Comment: This checks if there are any new(er) records in the table, not if the specific record was changed.

Comment: Take another look. Supplying "self" as the argument to exists will see if the record in question exists in the db in an updated state

Comment: Sorry, the argument was cropped by the code block, you are right :-)